# I'm trying to sync a gun which is a simple game object for my vr game in unity across multiple game clients using PUN"photon"

Tags: multiplayer, photon

I want to make a multiplayer game as I have mentioned. I have tried and I would like to sync all objects in the scene across all clients. I need to figure out how to fix it.

I tried using multiple tutorials none worked for my specific problem and I expected it to work none did.